# In GitlabCI - How can we trigger a build/pipeline if a specific build/pipeline is completed successfully?

Tags: gitlab-ci

We are using GitLab Enterprise Edition 10.8.7-ee 075705a and trying to use Gitlab CI.

Here is my scenario:-
I've two repositories repo1 and repo2 and I'm setting up two pipelines pipeline1 and pipeline2.

Now I'm looking for an option where I can configure pipeline2 to trigger a build if pipeline1 build is successful. One more thing, I need to get the version number of the pipeline1 in pipeline2

Note:- I know we can trigger pipeline2 from pipeline1 but I need other way around.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options. 
Use the gitlab api to do this (triggers).
Use webhooks to do this.

[gitlab webhooks docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) 
[gitlab triggers docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

with this. you can get any data / meta data for your stack. 
and can automagically call it/set it on any condition. 
This can also be done if your stack is using aws (CLI) and (or) Jenkins

Some sections that may interest you in [gitlab triggers docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

- When used with multi-project Pipelines
- When a pipeline depends on the artifacts of another Pipeline
- Triggering a pipeline from a webhook
- Using cron to trigger nightly (or pretty much *ly) pipelines

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe the gitlab wehooks are per repo but I need branch level triggering. For 'gitlab triggers', at a high level, I believe it useful when I want to trigger a pipeline2 from pipeline1. I'll deep dive into this. Thanks

Comment: Check out gitlab branching webhooks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992224/webhooks-for-branching-in-gitlab
Follow this gitlab proposal
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20338